# How can I change plane (inclination and OMEGA) during a bielliptical transfer?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, inclination-change

I'm trying to minimize deltav in a transfer between two elliptical orbits. The 'standard' strategy the professor provided consists in a change of inclination and RAAN and then a bielliptical or bitangent transfer.
I thought I could save some deltav if I did the change of inclination and RAAN at the apogee of the first elliptical transfer orbit. But how can I correct the pericenter anomaly?